# Question about limits of a convex function

Tags: limits, derivatives

Is the following conjecture true?
Suppose $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)} > 0$. Then $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) > -\infty$.

Comment: Your last limit does not make sense. A limit is greater than $-\infty$ ???

Comment: @Rustyn, why it does no make sense?

Comment: Have you tried something @TomH?

Comment: @Rustyn, it is a common notation used in plenty of books of Analysis, so I don't see what is the problem with it. Unless you want to be pedantic?

Comment: Just because something is common notation, doesn't mean I agree with it or I'm being pedantic.

Comment: Well @Rustyn , we have decades of mathematics using this notation. If you are not being pedantic, so I must conclude that you don't know it's meaning.

Comment: @Tomás Haha, sounds good, we'll go with that.

Comment: @Tomás: It is customary just to say that the limit exists, with the fact that the limit is finite being left implicit.

Comment: @copper.hat, I do agree with you, however, it is also costumary to use this form to avoid some technicalities, so in this way, $\infty$ or $-\infty$ are limits too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing our my sloppy notation. This notation is customary in my field and I think the meaning is clear, but I'm happy to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\dfrac{d}{dx} \ln(f') = f''(x)/f'(x) > \epsilon > 0$ for $x < A$, we have
$\ln(f'(x)) < \ln(f'(A)) + \epsilon (x-A)$, i.e. 
$f'(x) < e^{\epsilon (x-A)} f'(A)$, and 
$$f(x) = f(A) - \int_x^A f'(t)\; dt > f(A) + \dfrac{f'(A)}{\epsilon} \left(e^{-\epsilon A + \epsilon x} - 1 \right)$$
As $x \to -\infty$, the right side has a finite limit $f(A) - f'(A)/\epsilon$.
So $f$ is bounded below as $x \to -\infty$, and (since it is monotone) has a finite limit.

Comment: Why the downvote?